# Ros node does not recognize Haptic device

Tags: ros, force, usb, libusb, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing a ros node for reading Force Dimension Omega.x haptic device input.
I downloaded the Force Dimension SDK, compiled the libraries and exported them in /usr/local/lib while copied the headers in /usr/local/include. Then I modified CMakeLists.txt and package.xml to link those files. My code is building correctly now, but I can't connect to my haptic device. Since with other non-ros packages (e.g. Chai3D) I had to specify "sudo" for running a bin and for connecting to the haptic device properly, my question is: How I can run a ros node and connect to my device?
I am developing my code in QtCreator.

Looking forward for your help.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219395/ros-node-does-not-recognize-haptic-device/) by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2015-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally find out how to access to usb without typing sudo.
First of all, I create a new file in /etc/udev/rules.d named 10-mydevice.rules and added this line inside:

```
ATTRS{idProduct}=="[PRODUCT_ID]", ATTRS{idVendor}=="[VENDOR ID]", MODE="666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

where VENDOR_ID and PRODUCT_ID are specified by

```
lsusb -v
```

Then I simply checked if my user was part of plugdev group by typing

```
groups USERNAME
```

Finally I saved and closed my file and entered the following in the terminal window for refreshing the rules:

```
sudo udevadm trigger
```

Right now I can run my node by using rosrun without root privileges or run the node from inside QtCreator!!!
Hope this could help other people!

---

Originally posted by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) with karma: 191 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You most likely need to give your user access to the Linux *device file* that is used to communicate with the haptic device.

See [Rosrun as super user](http://answers.ros.org/question/189457/rosrun-as-super-user/) and replace `/dev/ttyUSB0` with the device file that is used by your haptic device driver.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) on 2015-10-19**:
Sorry but this does not help me.
I changed the owner of the bin file but it does not work with rosrun.
In addition, I noticed that I don't have /dev/ttyUSB0.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-20**:
Did you read the answer I linked to? Cause what you posted as an update to your question is exactly what those answers tell you to do.

**Comment by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) on 2015-10-20**:
Yes, I went through your links, but it took a while for understanding udev rules stuff. Anyway, your answer helped a lot.
Thanks!!

p.s. Sorry I am new to ros and linux and also to this forum. I edited my post but I cannot accept my answer.